# Laravel - Auth:attempt no password

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-4

My user migrate is:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('matricula')->unique();
$table->timestamps();
```

the user log in by 'matricula', i don't need password in my application, but the model User 'force' to use a password:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

...

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
```

How to authenticate without password?

Comment: you can set a default password in the database for every user and while log in the user just pass the default password with the username. This way you can save lot of work you have to do if you decide to change the L4 Auth working procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could eventually set the password field as the matricula.

Or, write your own Auth driver. By default L4 allows you to use username or password for login, so you can use one or the other, or both. In Laravel 3 you could specify which field to use as username (email or username).

Regards